On preference orders with the axiom of independence

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of all 1-dim probability distributions over $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and $\preccurlyeq$ a preference order on $\mathcal{M}$ (i.e. reflexive, transitive and complete) which satisfies the axiom of independence, e.g for all $F, G, H\in \mathcal{M}$ and for all $\alpha \in [0,1]$ we have
$$F \preccurlyeq G \iff (1-\alpha)F + \alpha H \preccurlyeq (1-\alpha) G + \alpha H.$$

Now, I want to show that if $\preccurlyeq$ satisfies the axiom of independence and $F \preccurlyeq G$, we get that the map
$$[0,1] \to \mathcal{M}; \quad \alpha \mapsto (1-\alpha)F + \alpha G$$
is monotone, i.e.
$$\alpha \leq \beta \iff (1-\alpha)F + \alpha G \preccurlyeq (1-\beta) F + \beta G.$$
I struggle proving this, first I tried assuming that $G \preccurlyeq H$ and then started with
$$(1-\alpha)F + \alpha G \preccurlyeq (1-\alpha)F + \alpha H \preccurlyeq (1-\alpha)G + \alpha H = G + \alpha(H - G) \preccurlyeq G + \beta(H - G) = (1-\beta)G + \beta H \preccurlyeq (1-\beta)F + \beta G,$$
but the last step is wrong in general. I guess this idea doesn't bring me anywhere.
I also thought about defining the $H$ somehow out of $F$ and $G$ with the $\alpha$ or $\beta$ as coefficient, but this also wasn't enough. Any help is appreciated!
